# How to sort a 3d array by multiple keys

Tags: python, sorting, multidimensional-array

I need to sort a 3d array by multiple keys, and i'm not familiar with lambda.
I have an array:

```py
arry = [,
    [[3,1,2], 'foo', 'bar'],
    [[1,2,3], 'foo', 'bar'],
    [[2,1,3], 'foo', 'bar']

    #[[x,y,z], 'blah', 'blah']
]
```

And i need to sort it so that the z value is **highest**, but if the `z` values equal, to sort by the `y` value **lowest**, and if `y` is equal, sort by `x` **lowest**. So the output array should look like this:

```py
arry = [
    [[2,1,3], 'foo', 'bar'],
    [[1,2,3], 'foo', 'bar'],
    [[3,1,2], 'foo', 'bar']

    #[[x,y,z], 'blah', 'blah']
]
```

Comment: Are you asking to sort w.r.t  x or y or z?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `sorted` with `key`:

```
sorted(arr, key=lambda x:(-x[0][2], x[0][1], x[0][0]))
```

Output:

```
[[[2, 1, 3], 'foo', 'bar'],
 [[1, 2, 3], 'foo', 'bar'],
 [[3, 1, 2], 'foo', 'bar']]
```

Note the `-` sign on `x[0][2]` to implement different criteria of comparison.